# How to reference a Element type in a schema file through a java class which comes from a external dependency

Tags: java, xml, xsd, jaxb, schema

I have a schema file with an element in it Example like below

```
  <xsd:complexType name="A">
   <xsd:sequence>
      <xsd:element name="Telephone" type="Type">
   </xsd:sequence>
 </xsd:complexType>
```

In the above-given example, I want to reference Element "Type" from a java class through a dependency I have added to my project. Is it possible to do so? I am pretty new to JAXB and schema related stuff.

Comment: `xjc` is a utility which can both create boilerplate JAXB code from an `xsd` file as you have, or the inverse operation.  Wikipedia has a general outline.  Do you need more info?

Comment: Yes, could you provide little more info if you have any? That would be helpful thanks.

Comment: "The tool "xjc" can be used to convert XML Schema and other schema file types (as of Java 1.6, RELAX NG, XML DTD, and WSDL are supported experimentally) to class representations." -wikipedia article on `jaxb`.  which references:  https://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/tools/share/xjc.html

Comment: `xjc` usage example:  https://stackoverflow.com/a/54165873/262852  note that the `xsd` schema file was **generated** through `trang`.  Your `xsd` file doesn't work.

Comment: Here's an article:  https://thoughts-on-java.org/generate-your-jaxb-classes-in-second/    but the problem is your `xsd` schema won't work, as you have it above, with `xjc`.  Which is why I reccomend `trang`.