# Validating xml against xsd file generated through JAXB and XSD build option in eclipse

Tags: java, xml, xsd, xml-validation

I am trying to have a sample code for validating my xml file against xsd file, which is getting generated through jaxb and xsd build through Eclipse.

I am trying to do a sample validator file, that validates my xml against my xsd file. Now, I have found a lot of examples for the java code, and I am using one of them. Also I have recieved a lot of answers for the issue that I am facing, but some way the answers suggests to either update my xsd or xml file. For me, I cannot do any of these, as I am generating the xsd files through jaxb and xsd build option through Eclipse.

```
try {
SchemaFactory factory = 
SchemaFactory.newInstance(XMLConstants.W3C_XML_SCHEMA_NS_URI);
Schema schema = factory.newSchema(new File(xsdPath));
Validator validator = schema.newValidator();
validator.validate(new StreamSource(new File(xmlPath)));
} catch (IOException e) {
System.out.println("Exception: "+e.getMessage());
return false;
} catch( SAXException e){
System.out.println("Exception: "+e.getMessage());
return false;
}
return true;
}

My XML File
<!DOCTYPE MLIspec SYSTEM "MLIspec-1.6.dtd"> 
<MLIspec> 
<id>4050response</id> 
<typename>4050Response</typename> 
<description>Show the Contract Numbers</description>    
<element> 
<id>7504</id> 
<name>SourceAccountIdentifier</name> 
<type>table</type> 
<required>true</required>       
</element>
</MLIspec>
XSD file

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><xs:schema xmlns:jxb="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/jaxb" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:cdcla="cdcla" jxb:version="1.0">
<xs:include schemaLocation="SourceAccountIdentifier.xsd"/>
<xs:complexType name="MXMLI4050Response">
<xs:annotation>
<xs:appinfo>
<jxb:class name="MXMLI4050Response">
<jxb:javadoc>4050response - MXMLI4050Response. Show the Contract Numbers. </jxb:javadoc>
</jxb:class>
<cdcla:elf group="true"/>
</xs:appinfo>
</xs:annotation>
<xs:all>
<xs:element name="e7920" type="xs:integer" minOccurs="0">
<xs:annotation>
<xs:documentation>MessageFunctionCode</xs:documentation>
<xs:appinfo>
<jxb:property name="MessageFunctionCode">
<jxb:javadoc>7920 - MessageFunctionCode. </jxb:javadoc>
<jxb:baseType>
<jxb:javaType name="java.lang.Integer" parseMethod="com.citigroup.cdcla.gmli.bind.DatatypeConverter.parseIntegerFromDatatypeN" printMethod="com.citigroup.cdcla.gmli.bind.DatatypeConverter.printIntegerAsDatatypeN"/>
</jxb:baseType>
</jxb:property>
</xs:appinfo>
</xs:annotation>
</xs:element>
<xs:element name="e8002" type="xs:integer" minOccurs="0">
<xs:annotation>
<xs:documentation>TerminalID</xs:documentation>
<xs:appinfo>
<jxb:property name="TerminalID">
<jxb:javadoc>8002 - TerminalID. </jxb:javadoc>
<jxb:baseType>
<jxb:javaType name="java.lang.Integer" parseMethod="com.citigroup.cdcla.gmli.bind.DatatypeConverter.parseIntegerFromDatatypeN" printMethod="com.citigroup.cdcla.gmli.bind.DatatypeConverter.printIntegerAsDatatypeN"/>
</jxb:baseType>
</jxb:property>
</xs:appinfo>
</xs:annotation>
</xs:element>
<xs:element name="e8005" type="xs:integer" minOccurs="0">
<xs:annotation>
<xs:documentation>MessageSequenceNumber</xs:documentation>
<xs:appinfo>
<jxb:property name="MessageSequenceNumber">
<jxb:javadoc>8005 - MessageSequenceNumber. </jxb:javadoc>
<jxb:baseType>
<jxb:javaType name="java.lang.Integer" parseMethod="com.citigroup.cdcla.gmli.bind.DatatypeConverter.parseIntegerFromDatatypeN" printMethod="com.citigroup.cdcla.gmli.bind.DatatypeConverter.printIntegerAsDatatypeN"/>
</jxb:baseType>
</jxb:property>
</xs:appinfo>
</xs:annotation>
</xs:element>
<xs:element name="e7300" type="xs:integer" minOccurs="0">
<xs:annotation>
<xs:documentation>AcquirerResponseCode</xs:documentation>
<xs:appinfo>
<jxb:property name="AcquirerResponseCode">
<jxb:javadoc>7300 - AcquirerResponseCode. </jxb:javadoc>
<jxb:baseType>
<jxb:javaType name="java.lang.Integer" parseMethod="com.citigroup.cdcla.gmli.bind.DatatypeConverter.parseIntegerFromDatatypeN" printMethod="com.citigroup.cdcla.gmli.bind.DatatypeConverter.printIntegerAsDatatypeN"/>
</jxb:baseType>
</jxb:property>
</xs:appinfo>
</xs:annotation>
</xs:element>
<xs:element name="e7302" type="xs:integer" minOccurs="0">
<xs:annotation>
<xs:documentation>ActionCode</xs:documentation>
<xs:appinfo>
<jxb:property name="ActionCode">
<jxb:javadoc>7302 - ActionCode. </jxb:javadoc>
<jxb:baseType>
<jxb:javaType name="java.lang.Integer" parseMethod="com.citigroup.cdcla.gmli.bind.DatatypeConverter.parseIntegerFromDatatypeN" printMethod="com.citigroup.cdcla.gmli.bind.DatatypeConverter.printIntegerAsDatatypeN"/>
</jxb:baseType>
</jxb:property>
</xs:appinfo>
</xs:annotation>
</xs:element>
<xs:element name="e40986" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0">
<xs:annotation>
<xs:documentation>ActionCodeDescription</xs:documentation>
<xs:appinfo>
<jxb:property name="ActionCodeDescription">
<jxb:javadoc>40986 - ActionCodeDescription. </jxb:javadoc>
</jxb:property>
</xs:appinfo>
</xs:annotation>
</xs:element>
<xs:element name="e7928" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0">
<xs:annotation>
<xs:documentation>HostID</xs:documentation>
<xs:appinfo>
<jxb:property name="HostID">
<jxb:javadoc>7928 - HostID. </jxb:javadoc>
</jxb:property>
</xs:appinfo>
</xs:annotation>
</xs:element>
<xs:element name="e8001" type="xs:integer" minOccurs="0">
<xs:annotation>
<xs:documentation>RetryFlag</xs:documentation>
<xs:appinfo>
<jxb:property name="RetryFlag">
<jxb:javadoc>8001 - RetryFlag. </jxb:javadoc>
<jxb:baseType>
<jxb:javaType name="java.lang.Integer" parseMethod="com.citigroup.cdcla.gmli.bind.DatatypeConverter.parseIntegerFromDatatypeN" printMethod="com.citigroup.cdcla.gmli.bind.DatatypeConverter.printIntegerAsDatatypeN"/>
</jxb:baseType>
</jxb:property>
</xs:appinfo>
</xs:annotation>
</xs:element>
<xs:element name="e47602" type="xs:integer" minOccurs="0">
<xs:annotation>
<xs:documentation>CustomerTypeCode</xs:documentation>
<xs:appinfo>
<jxb:property name="CustomerTypeCode">
<jxb:javadoc>47602 - CustomerTypeCode. </jxb:javadoc>
</jxb:property>
</xs:appinfo>
</xs:annotation>
</xs:element>
<xs:element name="e7504" type="SourceAccountIdentifier" maxOccurs="unbounded" minOccurs="0">
<xs:annotation>
<xs:documentation>SourceAccountIdentifierList</xs:documentation>
<xs:appinfo>
<jxb:property name="SourceAccountIdentifierList">
<jxb:javadoc>7504 - SourceAccountIdentifier Table. </jxb:javadoc>
</jxb:property>
<cdcla:elf group="true"/>
</xs:appinfo>
</xs:annotation>
</xs:element>
</xs:all>
</xs:complexType>
</xs:schema>
```

Below is the error that I am receiving
Exception: src-resolve: Cannot resolve the name 'SourceAccountIdentifier' to a(n) 'type definition' component.

Also, I tried to remove SourceAccountIdentifier from my xsd definition, to see if it fails anywhere else, in that case, I recieve the below error

```
Exception: src\main\java\com\citi\cbol\test\MLIspec-1.6.dtd (The system cannot find the file specified)
```

Please help to provide some solution for the error. Thanks!!

Comment: the Java code would be helpful to see what's going on.

Comment: the part starting from keyword "try" is the java code. Apologies for improper formatting.

Comment: you should be able to compile and run the project regardless of your IDE.  (You'll have to adjust the file, which is in the properties file.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**The generated code is on [github](https://github.com/THUFIR/xjc_generated-code) for you.**

I'm **gussing** that it's a problem with the `xml` or `xsd` files -- but I don't know for a fact.

I removed the `dtd` for now, here's what I have so far:

```
thufir@dur:~/xml/so$ 
thufir@dur:~/xml/so$ ls
foo.xml
thufir@dur:~/xml/so$ 
thufir@dur:~/xml/so$ cat foo.xml 
<MLIspec> 
<id>4050response</id> 
<typename>4050Response</typename> 
<description>Show the Contract Numbers</description>    
<element> 
<id>7504</id> 
<name>SourceAccountIdentifier</name> 
<type>table</type> 
<required>true</required>       
</element>
</MLIspec>
thufir@dur:~/xml/so$ 
thufir@dur:~/xml/so$ trang foo.xml foo.xsd
thufir@dur:~/xml/so$ 
thufir@dur:~/xml/so$ cat foo.xsd 
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" elementFormDefault="qualified">
  <xs:element name="MLIspec">
    <xs:complexType>
      <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element ref="id"/>
        <xs:element ref="typename"/>
        <xs:element ref="description"/>
        <xs:element ref="element"/>
      </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
  </xs:element>
  <xs:element name="typename" type="xs:NMTOKEN"/>
  <xs:element name="description" type="xs:string"/>
  <xs:element name="element">
    <xs:complexType>
      <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element ref="id"/>
        <xs:element ref="name"/>
        <xs:element ref="type"/>
        <xs:element ref="required"/>
      </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
  </xs:element>
  <xs:element name="name" type="xs:NCName"/>
  <xs:element name="type" type="xs:NCName"/>
  <xs:element name="required" type="xs:boolean"/>
  <xs:element name="id" type="xs:NMTOKEN"/>
</xs:schema>
thufir@dur:~/xml/so$ 
thufir@dur:~/xml/so$ xjc foo.xsd 
parsing a schema...
compiling a schema...
generated/Element.java
generated/MLIspec.java
generated/ObjectFactory.java
thufir@dur:~/xml/so$ 
thufir@dur:~/xml/so$ tree
.
├── foo.xml
├── foo.xsd
└── generated
    ├── Element.java
    ├── MLIspec.java
    └── ObjectFactory.java

1 directory, 5 files
thufir@dur:~/xml/so$
```

**The tools are `trang` and `xjc` which install on Ubuntu Linux easily enough.**  Here's how to run the project, which builds from the console:

```
thufir@dur:~/NetBeansProjects$ 
thufir@dur:~/NetBeansProjects$ cat /home/thufir/xml/output.xml 
cat: /home/thufir/xml/output.xml: No such file or directory
thufir@dur:~/NetBeansProjects$ 
thufir@dur:~/NetBeansProjects$ git clone git@github.com:THUFIR/xjc_generated-code.git
Cloning into 'xjc_generated-code'...
remote: Enumerating objects: 143, done.
remote: Counting objects: 100% (143/143), done.
remote: Compressing objects: 100% (81/81), done.
remote: Total 143 (delta 25), reused 120 (delta 11), pack-reused 0
Receiving objects: 100% (143/143), 79.43 KiB | 191.00 KiB/s, done.
Resolving deltas: 100% (25/25), done.
thufir@dur:~/NetBeansProjects$ 
thufir@dur:~/NetBeansProjects$ cd xjc_generated-code/
thufir@dur:~/NetBeansProjects/xjc_generated-code$ 
thufir@dur:~/NetBeansProjects/xjc_generated-code$ gradle clean run

> Task :run
Jan 17, 2019 2:34:06 PM xjc_generated.code.driver.App unmarshallMLI
INFO: generated.MLIspec@12edcd21

BUILD SUCCESSFUL in 1s
4 actionable tasks: 3 executed, 1 up-to-date
thufir@dur:~/NetBeansProjects/xjc_generated-code$ 
thufir@dur:~/NetBeansProjects/xjc_generated-code$ cat /home/thufir/xml/output.xml 
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<MLIspec>
    <id>4050response</id>
    <typename>4050Response</typename>
    <description>Show the Contract Numbers</description>
    <element>
        <id>7504</id>
        <name>SourceAccountIdentifier</name>
        <type>table</type>
        <required>true</required>
    </element>
</MLIspec>
thufir@dur:~/NetBeansProjects/xjc_generated-code$
```

That should work even from Eclipse.  Note that it's using gradle, or the Gradle Kotlin DSL for the build file, which Eclipse should be able to handle.  Probably you want to import as a gradle project.

You should only have to alter the `properties.xml` file [for your system](https://github.com/THUFIR/xjc_generated-code/blob/master/src/main/resources/properties.xml); the source code should be fine.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I will try the solution, as you suggested. For the part of dtd, let me try to get as much info , as I could. Thanks!!

Comment: I can put the generated code up for download.  The generated classes are rather spammy to post here.

Comment: If possible to put the code for download, will be very helpful.

Comment: look in the resources folder for the xml and xsd files, which were built as above.  also, the properties folder specifices where to load the file from and write files too, so you'll have to adjust for your system.  You should not have to change the Java source code at all, only the properties file, which is in the resources folder.